# Unhandled rejection AssertionError With Mocha

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, mocha.js

I am writing a Mocha test for a module I created in express. It gives me a error I dont understand how to fix.

The test:

```
  describe('userController', function() {
    describe('post -> /create', function() {
      it('A user should be created', () => {
          var testRequest = {
              body: {
                  password:"pass1",
                  email:"test@me.com",
                  username:"user1",
              }
          };
          database.registerUser(testRequest, (callBack) => {
              new User({email:"test@me.com"})
              .fetch()
              .then((model) => {
                 assert.equal(model.get('password'), testRequest.body.password);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                assert(false);
              });
          });
      });
    });
  });
```

The Error:

```
Unhandled rejection AssertionError: false == true
    at User.fetch.then.catch (/home/shanedrafahl/code/MyRentalServer/myRental/test/test.js:72:17)
    at tryCatcher (/home/shanedrafahl/code/MyRentalServer/myRental/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/shanedrafahl/code/MyRentalServer/myRental/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/shanedrafahl/code/MyRentalServer/myRental/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/shanedrafahl/code/MyRentalServer/myRental/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/shanedrafahl/code/MyRentalServer/myRental/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:689:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/home/shanedrafahl/code/MyRentalServer/myRental/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/shanedrafahl/code/MyRentalServer/myRental/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/home/shanedrafahl/code/MyRentalServer/myRental/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
```

If anybody could tell me or show me why it is giving me this error and how to fix it I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two problems here. The first is the actual problem. And the second is the problem with the test. Maybe solving the second will give you more information how to solve the first.

I'm not familiar with `assert`, but judging from your stack trace it seems you are expecting `assert` to do something else in this part:

```
.catch((err) => {
  assert(false);    // <---- test problem is with the first param being false
});
```

### Solution (to the test problem)

I think what you actually want is to print the content of `err`. With it you can understand why you get to `catch` at all.

Since your test is async I think you should use `done` like this:

```
it('A user should be created', (done) => {  //added done param
```

...

```
.then((model) => {
  assert.equal(model.get('password'), testRequest.body.password);
  done() // let mocha know the async test is done
})
.catch((err) => {
  done(err) // let mocha know the async test is done with an error, so it can display the error in the output
});
```

Now you should be able to test your code to find the other problem.

You can read about async testing with Mocha [here: Mocha - Asynchronous Code](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code)